# In drupal7 what should be the path to filter nodes with taxonomy terms

Tags: drupal-7

Hi what should be the url to get nodes that belongs to a particular taxonomy term.

Like if i want a json parse for (say) node 5 of a content type Books then the url will be
   www.websitename/api/node?parameters[type]=Books
or
for simply getting node it should be www.websitename/api/node/5

But how to get a node that belongs to a particular taxonomy(category)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are asking for.  Do you just want the archive for a particular taxonomy term?  You get that at yoursite.com/taxonomy/term/1  (but instead of "1" use the id for the term you are looking for, ID's are listed along with terms at structure - taxonomy - list terms)

If you want to do more complicated things, which I gather you do, it's a better idea to use the Views module to sort by taxonomy term and add whatever other sorts and filters you want.